# NullReferenceException thrown for an object (i.e. socket) that was checked to be null beforehand and is locked

Tags: c#, sockets, locking, nullreferenceexception

I am sure it is something silly that is being overlooked, but I have the **System.NullReferenceException** exception thrown on the line `_clientSocket.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data));` and can confirm that `_clientSocket` IS null when the exception is thrown.

But, in this case, I have two questions:

1. Why is the exception being thrown, if we have the lines before the Sent method is called purposed to check if the object is null and lock said object to prevent any other threads from disposing it?
2. Why is the exception NOT being caught?

   ```
   private bool SendToServer(string data)
   {
       Logger.Log($"[{_clientID}] sending the following to server: {data}", LoggingSeverity.trace);

       if (_clientSocket == null)
       {
           Logger.Log($"[{_clientID}] send failure. Socket not initialized.", LoggingSeverity.warning);
           return false;
       }

       lock (_clientSocket)
       {
           bool sendSuccessful = true;

           try
           {
               _clientSocket.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data));
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               Logger.Log($"[{_clientID}] client send exception: {ex.Message}", LoggingSeverity.warning);
               sendSuccessful = false;
           }

           if (!sendSuccessful)
           {
               try
               {
                   _clientSocket.Close();
               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {
                   Logger.Log($"[{_clientID}] client close exception: {ex.Message}", LoggingSeverity.warning);
               }
               _clientSocket = null;
               return false;
           }
       }
       Thread.Sleep(1000);
       return true;
   }
   ```

Thank you, everyone, for taking the time to look, provide feedback and thoughts, etc.

Comment: Is there any other code setting `_clientSocket = null`? If yes, does it also have a `lock (_clientSocket )`?

Comment: Correct - there is a lock around (_clientSocket) object any time that _clientSocket is used when it is NOT null (which does not require a lock, from my understanding).

Comment: My suspicion is that `GetBytes` may be a related culprit. But, it would not explain why _clientSocket is null when the exception is thrown.

Comment: It might well be that between the check for null and the lock the value changes. It is better to use another readonly object for locking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The critical area is your "_clientSocket" dear. You should avoid using "_clientSocket" for your lock object.
Do like this:

```
private static readonly _lock = new object();

private bool SendToServer(string data)
{
    Logger.Log($"[{_clientID}] sending the following to server: {data}", LoggingSeverity.trace);
    lock (_lock)
    {  
      if (_clientSocket == null)
      {
         Logger.Log($"[{_clientID}] send failure. Socket not initialized.", LoggingSeverity.warning);
         return false;
      }

      bool sendSuccessful = true;

      try
      {
        _clientSocket.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data));
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        Logger.Log($"[{_clientID}] client send exception: {ex.Message}", LoggingSeverity.warning);
        sendSuccessful = false;
      }

      if (!sendSuccessful)
      {
        try
        {
            _clientSocket.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Log($"[{_clientID}] client close exception: {ex.Message}", LoggingSeverity.warning);
        }
        _clientSocket = null;
        return false;
      }
  }
  Thread.Sleep(1000);
  return true;
```

}

The main problem occurs when you use "_clientSocket" as a lock. The previous thread finishes null-checking and sleeps, then the next thread starts executing the null-assignment code and sleeps, then context switches to the previous thread, and null-reference-exception will be raised.

Comment: This actually makes sense. Just didn't consider creating an object specifically for the purpose of locking the socket object.

Comment: If your container class is singleton there is no need to make the lock object "static". If you are not sure about the instantiation count of your container class, be aware of marking the lock object is static. (You can use lazy instantiation but it's not important dear ;-). And please mark my answer as true if you achived your goal <3